# afterStateUpdate on Repeater not working filament laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Hello i am facing an issue in filament v3.I am making an order form using repeater in which there is relation with product table. The thing i want to do is by selecting product in select the other fields that i created outside the repeater should update accordingly.So I am using afterStateUpdated on repeater. I changes the fields inside the repeater but the fields in the other section outside the repeater are not updating. heres the code:

```
Repeater::make('products')
                    ->relationship()

                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('product_id')
                            ->label("Products")
                            ->relationship('product','name')
                            ->options(
                                $products->mapWithKeys(function (Product $product) {
                                    return [$product->id => sprintf('%s ($%s)', $product->name, $product->price)];
                                })
                            )
                            ->disableOptionWhen(function ($value, $state, Get $get) {
                                return collect($get('../*.product_id'))
                                    ->reject(fn($id) => $id == $state)
                                    ->filter()
                                    ->contains($value);
                            })
                            ->required()

                            ->createOptionForm([
                                Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')
                                    ->image()
                                    ->required(),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255),
                                Forms\Components\RichEditor::make('description')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(65535)
                                    ->columnSpanFull(),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('sku')
                                    ->label('SKU')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('price')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255)
                                    ->numeric(),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('qty')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255)
                                    ->numeric(),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('availablity')
                                    ->options([
                                        "yes" => "Yes",
                                        'no' => "No"
                                    ])
                                    ->required(),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('brands')
                                    ->relationship('brands', 'name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->multiple()
                                    ->preload()
                                    ->createOptionForm([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Forms\Components\Toggle::make('active')
                                            ->required(),
                                    ]),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('categories')
                                    ->relationship('categories', 'name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->multiple()
                                    ->preload()
                                    ->createOptionForm([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('description')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Forms\Components\Toggle::make('active')
                                            ->required(),
                                    ]),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('warehouse_id')
                                    ->relationship('warehouse', 'name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->createOptionForm([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Toggle::make('active')
                                    ])
                            ])
                            // ->reactive()
                            // ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $set) {
                            //     $product = Product::find($state);
                            //     if ($product) {

                            //         $set('product_id', $state);
                            //         $set('price', $product->price);
                            //     }
                            // })

                            ->columnSpan([
                                "md" => 5
                            ]),
                        TextInput::make('amount')
                            ->numeric()
                            ->required()
                            ->reactive()
                            ->label('Quantity')
                            // ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $set, Get $get) {
                            //     $product = Product::find($get('product_id'));
                            //     if(isset($product->price)){
                            //         $set('price', $product->price *$state);
                            //     }

                            // })

                            ->default(1)
                            ->columnSpan([
                                "md" => 3
                            ]),
                        TextInput::make('price')
                            ->disabled()
                            ->numeric()
                            ->minValue('1')
                            ->required()
                            ->default(1)
                            ->dehydrated()
                            ->columnSpan([
                                "md" => 2
                            ]),

                    ])->columns(["md" => 10])
                    ->live()
                    // After adding a new row, we need to update the totals
                    ->afterStateUpdated(fn ($state) => dd($state))
                    // After deleting a row, we need to update the totals
                    ->deleteAction(
                        fn(Action $action) => $action->after(fn(Get $get, Set $set) => self::updateTotals($get, $set)),
                    )
                    // Disable reordering
                    ->reorderable(false)
            ])->collapsible(),
```

the other section code is here:

```
Section::make()
            ->columns(1)
            ->maxWidth('1/2')->schema([
                TextInput::make('subtotal')
                ->numeric()
                ->readOnly()
                ->afterStateHydrated(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
                    self::updateTotals($get, $set);
                }),
                // TextInput::make('taxes')->required()->numeric()->default()
                TextInput::make('total')->readOnly()->numeric()
            ])
```

and the function updateTotals is here:

```
public static function updateTotals(Get $get, Set $set): void
```

{
// Retrieve all selected products and remove empty rows
$selectedProducts = collect($get('products'))->filter(fn($item) => !empty($item['product_id']) && !empty($item['amount']));

```
// Retrieve prices for all selected products
$prices = Product::find($selectedProducts->pluck('product_id'))->pluck('price', 'id');

// Calculate subtotal based on the selected products and quantities
$subtotal = $selectedProducts->reduce(function ($subtotal, $product) use ($prices) {
    return $subtotal + ($prices[$product['product_id']] * $product['amount']);
}, 0);

// Update the state with the new values
$set('subtotal', number_format($subtotal, 2, '.', ''));
$set('total', number_format($subtotal + ($subtotal * ($get('taxes') / 100)), 2, '.', ''));
```

}

i have taken this code from laravel Daily heres the link:[code picked from here](https://laraveldaily.com/post/filament-repeater-live-calculations-on-update)

Answer (score 0):

On your Repeater you have:

```
->afterStateUpdated(fn ($state) => dd($state))
```

Is it the problem?

Comment: i am using this but afterStateUpdated is not working.`->afterStateUpdated(function (Get $get, Set $set) {

                            self::updateTotals($get, $set);
                            $set('price',$get('product_id'));
                        })`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using stateUpdate On repeater i have used placeholder and inside placeholder i am getting repeater fields and achieving the required results as follow

```
return $form
        ->schema([
            Section::make('Customer Details')->schema([
                Forms\Components\Select::make('customer_id')
                    ->relationship('customer', 'name')
                    ->preload()
                    ->createOptionForm([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('phone_no')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('email')
                            ->email()
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                    ])
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('invoice_no')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\DateTimePicker::make('order_date')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('order_status')
                    ->options([
                        "received" => "Received",
                        "pending" => "Pending",
                        "ordered" => "Ordered"

                    ])
                    ->required(),

                FileUpload::make('document'),
                TextInput::make('total')->hidden()->disabled()
                ->dehydrated()
            ])->collapsed()->columns(2),

            Section::make('Product Details')->schema([
                Repeater::make('products')
                    ->relationship()
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('product_id')
                            ->label("Products")
                            ->relationship('product','name')
                            ->live()

                            ->required()

                            ->createOptionForm([
                                Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')
                                    ->image()
                                    ->required(),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255),
                                Forms\Components\RichEditor::make('description')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(65535)
                                    ->columnSpanFull(),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('sku')
                                    ->label('SKU')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255),
                                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('price')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->maxLength(255)
                                    ->numeric(),

                                Forms\Components\Select::make('availablity')
                                    ->options([
                                        "yes" => "Yes",
                                        'no' => "No"
                                    ])
                                    ->required(),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('brands')
                                    ->relationship('brands', 'name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->multiple()
                                    ->preload()
                                    ->createOptionForm([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Forms\Components\Toggle::make('active')
                                            ->required(),
                                    ]),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('categories')
                                    ->relationship('categories', 'name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->multiple()
                                    ->preload()
                                    ->createOptionForm([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('description')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Forms\Components\Toggle::make('active')
                                            ->required(),
                                    ]),
                                Forms\Components\Select::make('warehouse_id')
                                    ->relationship('warehouse', 'name')
                                    ->required()
                                    ->createOptionForm([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                                            ->required()
                                            ->maxLength(255),
                                        Toggle::make('active')
                                    ])
                            ])
                            ->reactive()
                            ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $set) {
                                $product = Product::find($state);
                                if ($product) {

                                    $set('product_id', $state);
                                    $set('price', $product->price);
                                }
                            })

                            ->columnSpan([
                                "md" => 5
                            ]),
                        TextInput::make('amount')
                            ->numeric()
                            ->required()
                            ->live(onBlur:true)
                            ->label('Quantity')
                            ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $set, Get $get) {
                                $product = Product::find($get('product_id'));
                                if(isset($product->price)){
                                    $set('price', $product->price *$state);
                                }

                            })

                            ->default(1)
                            ->columnSpan([
                                "md" => 3
                            ]),
                        TextInput::make('price')
                            ->disabled()
                            ->numeric()
                            ->required()
                            ->dehydrated()
                            ->columnSpan([
                                "md" => 2
                            ]),

                    ])->columns(["md" => 10])
                    ->live()
                    ->defaultItems(0)
            ])->collapsible(),

            Section::make()->schema([
                TextInput::make("amount")
                            ->label("Total Price")
                            ->disabled()
                            ->placeholder(function (Get $get , callable $set) {
                                $fields = $get('products');
                                $sum = 0;
                                foreach($fields as $field){
                                    // foreach ($field as $value){
                                    //     if ($value == ""){
                                    //         $value = 0;
                                    //     }
                                    //     elseif(is_numeric($value)){
                                    //         $sum += $value;
                                    //     }

                                    // }
                                    $sum+=$field['price'];
                                }
                                $set('total',$sum);
                                return $sum;
                            }),
                        //

            ]),

        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you've picked up same example used on Laravel Daily. I just had same situation and if you check comments on blog post https://laraveldaily.com/post/filament-repeater-live-calculations-on-update
you will see suggested example using LiveWire. Issue is mainly in statePath for your livewire state. Check example below and modify to your needs. Check comments on link above for details on where the problem was and how it's resolved. There are always different ways.

LiveWire is way to go:

```php
public static function updateTotals(Get $get, $livewire): void
    {
        // Retrieve the state path of the form. Most likely it's `data` but it could be something else.
        $statePath = $livewire->getFormStatePath();

        $products = data_get($livewire, $statePath . '.quoteProducts');
        if (collect($products)->isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        $selectedProducts = collect($products)->filter(fn($item) => !empty($item['product_id']) && !empty($item['quantity']));

        $prices = collect($products)->pluck('price', 'product_id');

        $subtotal = $selectedProducts->reduce(function ($subtotal, $product) use ($prices) {
            return $subtotal + ($prices[$product['product_id']] * $product['quantity']);
        }, 0);

        data_set($livewire, $statePath . '.subtotal', number_format($subtotal, 2, '.', ''));
        data_set($livewire, $statePath . '.total', number_format($subtotal + ($subtotal * (data_get($livewire, $statePath . '.taxes') / 100)), 2, '.', ''));
    }
```

Assuming that your "Total" field is like this and passing in `$livewire` as well.

```php
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('subtotal')
                ->numeric()
                // Read-only, because it's calculated
                ->readOnly()
                ->prefix('€')
                // This enables us to display the subtotal on the edit page load
                ->afterStateHydrated(function (Get $get, Set $set, \Livewire\Component $livewire) {
                    self::updateTotals($get, $set, $livewire);
                }),
```