# Laravel Filament: How to sum fields from Repeater

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have a problem how to calculate the total value of the products added to the order in Repeater. I need to calculate all the products and enter the total value in the database.

[image]
The database structure is

**orders**

```
id, number, customer_id, total_amount
```

**order_item**

```
id, order_id, product_id, qty, unit_price
```

**Code**

```
Forms\Components\Grid::make()->schema([

    Forms\Components\Repeater::make('items')
        ->relationship()
        ->required()
        ->label(false)
        ->addActionLabel('Add product')
        ->schema([
    
            // Select product

            Select::make('product_id')
                ->options(Product::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                ->label('Product')
                ->reactive()
                ->searchable()
                ->required()
                ->columnStart(1)
                ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, Set $set) {
                    $set('unit_price', Product::find($state)?->price ?? 0);
                }),
    
            // Unit price

            TextInput::make('unit_price')->columnStart(2)->readOnly(),
    

            // Quantity

            TextInput::make('qty')
                ->numeric()
                ->default(1)
                ->minValue(1)
                ->required()
                ->live()
                ->reactive()
                ->dehydrated()
                ->columnStart(3),
    
    ])->columnSpan('full'),
```

**What i try to put in repeater**

```
Forms\Components\Placeholder::make('total_amount')
    ->default(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
        $r = $get('qty') * $get('unit_price');
        $set('total_amount', $r);
    })
```

I tried with the following example and it calculates only for one repeater field. I need to calculate the total value of all Repeater fields and save it in the database in the order table in the `total_amount' column.
After submitting the form, nothing is entered into the database and I don't get any results. Number 2 in the screenshot is an example that is not relevant to this problem, it was a test and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put `->live()` to the repeater and use the 'items' in the `$get('items')`?

```
Forms\Components\Repeater::make('items')        
   ->live()
   ->afterStateUpdated(function (Set $set, Get $get) { 
       $items = $get('items');
       // calculate sum
       $set('total_amount', $sum);
   })
```

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/advanced#generating-a-slug-from-a-title

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77580810/22993404